# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'letters'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to import cryptography for my project, but for some reason when I try to install it, I get No module named 'letters'. Through pip and pip3 it worked without any problem, but when I want to install it from settings in PyCharm, the error pops out.

Comment: Are you using python2 or 3 ?

Comment: I'm using python3

Comment: Turns out I needed to change interpreter from python 3.8 to 3.9, although it's weird that it worked fine until now.